# NSNotificationCenter.PostNotificationName() with NULL object does not trigger: bug or as designed?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter

I'm subscribing to my own notifications using code like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("BL_UIIdleTimerFired", delegate {
    Console.WriteLine("BaseFolderViewController: idle timer fired");
});
```

To send a notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("BL_UIIdleTimerFired", null);
```

However, the notification will only be received correctly if the "anObject" parameter of `PostNotificationName(string sString, object anObject)` is not NULL.

Is this by design? Do I have to pass an object? Or is it a bug?
I don't really want to send a reference to a specific object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is by design. Apple's documentation for the other overload ([postNotificationName:object:userInfo:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName%3aobject%3auserInfo%3a)) states that the userInfo parameter can be null. So I suppose the other two cannot be null.

The "anObject" parameter is the object that posts the notification (sender) and the one that can be retrieved from NSNotification class' Object parameter.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in MonoTouch. NSNotification is built so you can send an optional dictionary and an optional object, which is normally the sender, but can be other objects as well. Both of these can be null, but in MonoTouch passing a null as the object parameter causes a Null Pointer Exception.

Its quite clear from the iOS documentation, regarding the Object parameter:
The object associated with the notification. This is often the object that posted this notification. It may be nil.

```
public void SendNotification()
{
    NSNotification notification = NSNotification.FromName("AwesomeNotification",new NSObject());            
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification(notification);
}

public void StartListeningForNotification()
{
    NSString name = new NSString("AwesomeNotification");
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this,new Selector("AwesomeNotificationReceived:"),name,null);            
}

public void StopListeningForNotification()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(this,"AwesomeNotification",null);             
}

[Export("AwesomeNotificationReceived:")]
public void AwesomeNotificationReceived(NSNotification n)
{

}
```